# understanding of different definition of transitive closure

Tags: abstract-algebra, relations

I'm familiar with the definition of transitive closure, how to find it and its general properties. However, I've run across a different way of defining transitive closure and it is not so intuitive for me. I am hoping someone here can unpack this into words so that this new definition is intuitive for me.

Definition:

Let $X$ be a finite set. Let $B$ be a binary relation on $X$. Then there is a binary relation $T_B$ , called the transitive closure of $B$, defined as:

$\forall {x,y} \in X$  $x  {T_B}  y$  iff $\exists$ {$x_i$}$_{i=1}^{n} $ $n \geq 1$ where $x_1=x, x_n=y,$$ x_1 B x_2,x_2B x_3.......x_{n-2}B x_{n-1}, x_{n-1} B x_n $

Answer (score 1):

$T_B$ defined like this is characterized by:

- $B\subseteq T_B$
- $T_B$ is transitive
- if $R$ is a transitive relation on $X$ and $B\subseteq R$ then $T_B\subseteq R$

In words $T_B$ is the smallest transitive relation on $X$ that contains $B$ as a subset.

A relation $R$ on a set $X$ is transitive if $xRy\wedge yRz\implies xRz$

Comment: I know all of those things to be true about transitive closures. I am just not sure how a person knows those things from this definition explicitly.

Comment: $n=2$ tells you that $B\subseteq T_B$. Do you see why $T_B$ is transitive?

Comment: $T_b$ is necessarily transitive because it is the transitive closure of B. I think a better way to communicate this question is: If I had never been exposed to transitive closure how would I be able to use this and only this definition to fully understand transitive closure.

Comment: I meant: do you see why $T_B$ is transitive *on base of the definition* mentioned in your question? There are (at least) two ways to define the transitive closure of a relation $B$. One of them is: the intersection of all transitive relations that contain $B$ as a subset. This is "from top to bottom". The other is the definition mentioned in your question. That is "from bottom to top". You start with $B$ and then you expand it ($n=1,2,\dots$ et cetera). Also this is called an "inductive" definition.